# Correctly implement subtraction operator with big integers

Tags: c++, list, operator-overloading, biginteger

I am writing a program that handles big integers stored in lists and is able to perform comparisons and operators through overloading. I am having trouble overloading the subtraction operator, the program will compile but the operation results in wrong outcomes.

**operator- section:**

```
BigInt BigInt::operator-(BigInt addend2) {
    BigInt total;
    short int first, second, result;

    list<short int>::reverse_iterator
        it1 = myList.rbegin(),
        it2 = addend2.myList.rbegin();

    while (it1 != myList.rend() || it2 != addend2.myList.rend()) {
        if (it1 != myList.rend()) { first = *it1; }
        else { first = 0; }
        if (it2 != addend2.myList.rend()) { second = *it2; }
        else { second = 0; }


        if (first < second) {
            first = first + 1000;
            short int temp = first - second;
            result = temp % 1000;
            first = first - 1000;
        }
        else {
            long int temp = first - second;
            result = temp % 1000;
        }

        if (it1 != myList.rend()) {
            it1++;
            if (first < second) {
                first = *it1;
                first = first - 1;
                *it1 = first;
            }
        }

        if (it2 != addend2.myList.rend()) { it2++; }
        total.myList.push_front(result);
    }
    return total;
}
```

When I run in a test file such as below:

```
cout << "\nThe subtraction of\n\t"
           << number1 << " - " << number2
           << "\nis\n\t" << number1 - number2 << endl;
```

I receive an output such as:

```
Enter a big integer:
50000
Enter another big integer:
20800
The sum of
        50000
 + 20800

is
        70800


The bigger number of
        50000

and
        20800

is
        50000


The subtraction of
        4-1000
 - 20800

is
        299999200


Add more integers (Y or N)?
```

Why does the subtraction operator print out an unintended result?

Comment: *the program will compile* -- All this means is that there are no syntax errors.  This has nothing to do with whether the program has logic / runtime bugs.  Please [read this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What kind of number is `4-1000` and what is the expected result? Is your number two's complement or sign-magnitude? For addition, there is no big difference. But for subtraction, there is. In two's complement, you simply add or subtract and the sign of the top limb determines the sign. **In sign-magnitude, you always subtract the smaller absolute value from the larger absolute value** and adjust the sign accordingly. And addition with different signs becomes subtraction and subtraction with equal signs becomes addition. You find the logic. Obviously your logic above doesn't work.